# How do I display the correct number of comments for my status system?

Tags: php

I'm creating a system where users can write their current status and other users can comment.

If anyone has commented on a user's status the user will get notified, but I'm having an issue coding this behavior.

My desired behavior is this: if i have one comment on my status (by one user, of course):

```
echo "user has commented your status"
```

If I have two comments in 2 of my statuses (and the both are from same user):

```
"user has commented your status" 
"user has commented your status"
```

(the text should be printed twice, each for one status)

If I have 3 comments in my 2 statuses (where the 1st status has 1 comment from one user, and the second has 2 by different users)

```
echo "More than one users has commented your status"
echo "user has commented your status"
```

So if I have 2 comments in 1 status (where both comments are different user and NOT the same)

```
echo "More than one users has commented your status"
```

To summarize: my system should only echo one time for EACH status notification. If its one comment from one user, or more comment in one status, from one user, you will get:

```
echo "user has commented your status"
```

but if comments come from different users in one status,  you will get:

```
echo "more than one has commented your status
```

When a user comments, it also saves in `users_msgs` a row, with:

```
uID | nData | icon
```

- `uID` contains the status creator's id (not the id of the user who commented)
- `icon` contains the commenting user's id.
- `nData` contains the status id.

(please do not comment on the names of the columns)

How can I do this? I don't know where to start.

The only thing that I know should be done is that in the query should be `uID = '$USER'` (where `$USER` is the id of the signed-in user). But how do I check if there's more than one user that has commented per status id (`nData`), and if not show a single message of `user has commented on your status`.

If something's unclear please comment and I'll update my question.

Comment: @Mark E, the title you changed could be misunderstood..

Comment: then change it to something which is less ambiguous but more meaningful than your original title of "how do I do this?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change how you're querying.  What you want to find is the number of users that have commented on a particular status and the number of comments.  Based on those two pieces of information you can determine what to print.

If you use `GROUP BY` grouping statements you can aggregate data about each status message.  You should group by the id of the status message, this is `nData`.  Then all you need to do is count the number of unique users (that's unique values of `icon`) and also the raw number of comments, which can be achieved using `COUNT(*)`.

```
 SELECT uID, nData, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT icon) as num_commenting_users, 
     COUNT(*) as num_comments 
 FROM users_msgs WHERE uID=$USER GROUP BY nData
```

Now `num_commenting_users` will tell you the number of unique users that have commented on status with id `nData`, and `num_comments` will tell you how many comments have been made on status with id `nData`.

For each row returned by this query, you can then do a simple check, if there are more than 1 unique commenting users, print "more than one has commented your status", else print "user has commented your status":

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($row['num_commenting_users'] > 1){
        echo "more than one has commented your status";
    }else{
        // we know there was at least one comment made, and
        // even if many comments were made, they were all made
        // by the same user (since there was exactly 1 num_commenting_users)
        echo "user has commented your status";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. But shouldnt this be in a while? So it echo's "more than" or "user" for each status? How can i do this in a while, could you show me?

Comment: for now it works like a charm but i just need to check one thing

Comment: Okay thank you works great!! Although need alittle help: in where its "more than" I want to use columns: echo $row['nData'] , and $row['nData2'] and in the "user has commented your status" i need header, msg and icon columns to echo. How can i select them with the query?

Comment: @Johnson `nData`, is already selected, put `nData2` in the list if you want to use it. Since there can be multiple values for `icon` it doesn't make sense to select the value using this query.

Comment: So i just add what i need of columns after      COUNT(*) as num_comments, nData2, header, msg....?

Comment: @Johnson, generally, yes. It might be worth it to take a look at some tutorials on whatever database you're using if you don't understand that already.

Comment: I do, just was worried maybe if it would affect the GROUP BY and COUNT stuff as this is new for me, I would like to select icon to show a user´s(id of the user is in icon) profilephoto, thats why. Thank you for fast help, great answer, you rock at explaining +1!

Answer (score 0):

For each status change of each user you should have "not read comments count" variable. For example, user "USER" has changed his status twice:

```
user_id  status  not_read_comments_count
USER     BUSY    0
USER     AVAIL   0
```

And people has left some comments on the status changes:

```
user_id  status  not_read_comments_count
USER     BUSY    2
USER     AVAIL   1
```

When "USER" comes back to site and reads his profile, your program reads "not_read_comments_count" for each status change and yields:

"You have 2 comments on your status"
   "You have 1 comment on yout status"

and right after yielding it resets all "not_read_comments_count" to 0:

```
user_id  status  not_read_comments_count
USER     BUSY    0
USER     AVAIL   0
```

Comment: Wow i did not understand any of what you ment, and why you have "busy, avaible" and not_read_comments_count. Besides i wish to have have it work how i wanted with the current columns and table i have. Please take your time and read over again

Comment: Sorry, forgot to look at your table. The task can not be completed without at least one column, either "not read comments count" or "is comment read? (yes/no)".

Comment: readed by who?.. the one who created the status? there's a viewed column for this, 0 for not viewed 1 for viewed.. but this is just something you would insert as "WHERE viewed = '0'" in the query that shall be made for doing this..

Comment: Readed by one who created status. OK, there is "viewed" column, and it should be used for this. Let me think...